# Joined -> True works incorrectly for the given data set

Tags: plotting, syntax

Consider a set of data

```
DataTable ={{0.484785, 0.824468}, {0.48475, 0.696228}, {0.484839, 0.616711}, {0.484929, 0.546276}, {0.485019, 0.483885}, {0.485108, 0.42862}, 

  {0.485563, 0.373584}, {0.486006, 0.3308}, {0.486096, 0.293019}, {0.486186, 0.259553}, {0.486276, 0.229909}, {0.486366, 0.203651}, 

  {0.486455, 0.180392}, {0.486545, 0.159789}, {0.486635, 0.141539}, {0.486725, 0.125374}, {0.486815, 0.111055}, {0.486905, 0.0983712}, 

  {0.486995, 0.0871361}, {0.487085, 0.0771842}, {0.487175, 0.0683689}, {0.487265, 0.0605604}, {0.487356, 0.0536437}, {0.487446, 0.047517}, 

  {0.487536, 0.0420901}, {0.487626, 0.0372829}, {0.48747, 0.0327309}, {0.487659, 1.00471}, {0.488162, 0.0291998}, {0.488253, 0.0258648}, 

  {0.488343, 0.0229108}, {0.488433, 0.0202941}, {0.488523, 0.0179763}, {0.488614, 0.0159232}, {0.488704, 0.0141046}, {0.488794, 0.0124937}, 

  {0.488885, 0.0110668}, {0.488975, 0.00980283}, {0.489066, 0.00868324}, {0.489156, 0.00769152}, {0.489246, 0.00681306}, {0.489337, 0.00603493}, 

  {0.489427, 0.00534568}, {0.489518, 0.00473514}, {0.489971, 0.00415605}, {0.490062, 0.00368138}, {0.490152, 0.00326093}, {0.490243, 0.00288849}, 

  {0.490334, 0.00255859}, {0.490424, 0.00226637}, {0.490515, 0.00200753}, {0.490606, 0.00177825}, {0.490696, 0.00157515}, {0.490787, 0.00139525}, 

  {0.490878, 0.0012359}, {0.490969, 0.00109474}, {0.491059, 0.000969712}, {0.49115, 0.00085896}, {0.491241, 0.000760858}, {0.491332, 0.000673959}, 

  {0.491423, 0.000596986}, {0.491514, 0.000528803}, {0.491604, 0.000468408}, {0.491695, 0.00041491}, {0.491786, 0.000367523}, {0.491538, 0.000317639}, 

  {0.495209, 0.000284014}, {0.495511, 1.01714}, {0.503222, 0.000272958}, {0.503498, 1.01754}, {0.511361, 0.000263783}, {0.511614, 1.01793}, 

  {0.51963, 0.0002553}, {0.519861, 1.01833}, {0.528033, 0.00024709}, {0.528241, 1.01872}, {0.536573, 0.000238665}, {0.536756, 1.01912}, 

  {0.545249, 0.000231105}, {0.545409, 1.01951}, {0.554061, 0.000225248}, {0.5542, 1.01991}, {0.563012, 0.0002202}, {0.563134, 1.0203}, 

  {0.572113, 0.000213867}, {0.572211, 1.0207}, {0.581379, 0.000203594}, {0.581435, 1.02109}, {0.590782, 0.000196652}, {0.590808, 1.02149}, 

  {0.600335, 0.000190423}, {0.600331, 1.02188}, {0.610043, 0.000184299}, {0.610008, 1.02228}, {0.619908, 0.000178462}, {0.619842, 1.02268}, 

  {0.62993, 0.000173069}, {0.629833, 1.02307}, {0.640116, 0.000167587}, {0.639986, 1.02347}, {0.650466, 0.000162523}, {0.650302, 1.02387}, 

  {0.660984, 0.000157375}, {0.660785, 1.02426}, {0.67167, 0.00015262}, {0.671436, 1.02466}, {0.682528, 0.000148231}, {0.68226, 1.02506}, 

  {0.693565, 0.000143464}, {0.693257, 1.02545}, {0.704777, 0.000139268}, {0.704432, 1.02585}, {0.716173, 0.000134925}, {0.715788, 1.02625}, 

  {0.727752, 0.000130848}, {0.727326, 1.02665}, {0.739518, 0.000126957}, {0.73905, 1.02704}, {0.751473, 0.000123244}, {0.750963, 1.02744}, 

  {0.76362, 0.00011976}, {0.763069, 1.02784}, {0.775968, 0.000115967}, {0.775369, 1.02824}, {0.788512, 0.000112632}, {0.787868, 1.02864}, 

  {0.80126, 0.000109283}, {0.800568, 1.02904}, {0.814212, 0.000106193}, {0.813473, 1.02944}, {0.827376, 0.000102985}, {0.826585, 1.02983}, 

  {0.84075, 0.000100073}, {0.83991, 1.03023}, {0.85434, 0.0000972926}, {0.853449, 1.03063}, {0.868152, 0.0000943999}, {0.867206, 1.03103}, 

  {0.882183, 0.0000919152}, {0.881185, 1.03143}, {0.896443, 0.0000892718}, {0.895389, 1.03183}, {0.910933, 0.0000867915}, {0.909823, 1.03223}, 

  {0.925657, 0.0000844223}, {0.924489, 1.03263}, {0.940621, 0.0000819534}, {0.939391, 1.03303}, {0.955822, 0.0000798362}, {0.954534, 1.03343}, 

  {0.971271, 0.0000776959}, {0.969921, 1.03383}, {0.986968, 0.0000756508}, {0.985555, 1.03423}, {1.00292, 0.0000734384}, {1.00144, 1.03463}, 

  {1.01913, 0.0000717207}, {1.01758, 1.03503}, {1.0356, 0.0000696581}, {1.03399, 1.03544}, {1.05233, 0.0000680288}, {1.05066, 1.03584}, 

  {1.06934, 0.0000661387}, {1.06759, 1.03624}, {1.08662, 0.000064527}, {1.0848, 1.03664}, {1.10418, 0.0000629231}, {1.10229, 1.03704}, 

  {1.12203, 0.0000612669}, {1.12006, 1.03744}, {1.14016, 0.000059714}, {1.13811, 1.03785}, {1.15858, 0.0000583466}, {1.15646, 1.03825}, 

  {1.1773, 0.0000568963}, {1.1751, 1.03865}, {1.19632, 0.0000555934}, {1.19404, 1.03905}, {1.21565, 0.0000541843}, {1.21329, 1.03946}, 

  {1.23529, 0.0000530498}, {1.23285, 1.03986}, {1.25525, 0.0000518869}, {1.25272, 1.04026}, {1.27553, 0.0000506733}, {1.27291, 1.04066}, 

  {1.29613, 0.0000496371}, {1.29343, 1.04107}, {1.31707, 0.0000484761}, {1.31428, 1.04147}, {1.33834, 0.0000475086}, {1.33547, 1.04187}, 

  {1.35996, 0.0000464905}, {1.35699, 1.04228}, {1.38193, 0.0000455855}, {1.37887, 1.04268}, {1.40424, 0.000044743}, {1.40109, 1.04309}, 

  {1.42693, 0.000043828}, {1.42368, 1.04349}, {1.44997, 0.0000429749}, {1.44663, 1.0439}, {1.47338, 0.0000423076}, {1.46995, 1.0443}, 

  {1.49718, 0.0000414632}, {1.49364, 1.0447}, {1.52135, 0.0000408603}, {1.51772, 1.04511}, {1.54591, 0.0000402259}, {1.54218, 1.04551}, 

  {1.57087, 0.000039522}, {1.56704, 1.04592}, {1.59623, 0.0000389278}, {1.5923, 1.04632}, {1.62199, 0.0000385159}, {1.61797, 1.04673}, 

  {1.64817, 0.0000379559}, {1.64405, 1.04714}, {1.67478, 0.0000374415}, {1.67055, 1.04754}, {1.7018, 0.0000370639}, {1.69748, 1.04795}, 

  {1.72926, 0.0000366534}, {1.72485, 1.04835}, {1.75716, 0.0000363565}, {1.75265, 1.04876}, {1.78552, 0.0000359358}, {1.7809, 1.04917}, 

  {1.81432, 0.0000357162}, {1.80961, 1.04957}, {1.84358, 0.0000355693}, {1.83878, 1.04998}, {1.87332, 0.0000352635}, {1.86842, 1.05039}, 

  {1.9035, 0.00003549}, {1.89854, 1.05079}, {1.9342, 0.0000352732}, {1.92914, 1.0512}, {1.96592, 0.0000346258}, {1.9881, 0.0000309439}, 

  {1.96024, 1.05161}, {2.0209, 0.00003026}, {1.99184, 1.05202}, {2.05348, 0.0000302566}, {2.02395, 1.05242}, {2.08656, 0.0000304204}, 

  {2.05657, 1.05283}, {2.12022, 0.0000302649}, {2.08972, 1.05324}, {2.15438, 0.0000304135}, {2.12341, 1.05365}, {2.18908, 0.0000306241}, 

  {2.15764, 1.05406}, {2.22434, 0.0000308981}, {2.19242, 1.05446}, {2.26018, 0.0000311121}, {2.22776, 1.05487}, {2.29656, 0.000031564}, 

  {2.26367, 1.05528}, {2.33355, 0.0000318623}, {2.30016, 1.05569}, {2.37111, 0.0000323737}, {2.33723, 1.0561}, {2.40925, 0.0000331084}, 

  {2.37491, 1.05651}, {2.448, 0.0000339106}, {2.41319, 1.05692}, {2.48736, 0.0000347845}, {2.45209, 1.05733}, {2.52738, 0.000035467}, 

  {2.49162, 1.05774}, {2.56801, 0.0000364906}, {2.53178, 1.05815}, {2.6093, 0.0000375061}, {2.57259, 1.05856}, {2.65124, 0.0000386853}, 

  {2.61406, 1.05897}, {2.69381, 0.0000403238}, {2.6562, 1.05938}, {2.73705, 0.000042116}, {2.69902, 1.05979}, {2.78105, 0.0000433749}, 

  {2.74253, 1.0602}, {2.82572, 0.0000449634}, {2.78673, 1.06061}, {2.8711, 0.0000467739}, {2.83165, 1.06102}, {2.9172, 0.0000487061}, 

  {2.8773, 1.06143}, {2.96405, 0.0000506674}, {2.92368, 1.06184}, {3.01167, 0.0000524967}, {2.97081, 1.06226}, {3.06007, 0.0000542287}, 

  {3.0187, 1.06267}, {3.10925, 0.0000559617}, {3.06736, 1.06308}, {3.15924, 0.0000574327}, {3.1168, 1.06349}, {3.21004, 0.000059031}, 

  {3.16704, 1.0639}, {3.26166, 0.0000605827}, {3.2181, 1.06432}, {3.3141, 0.0000622687}, {3.26997, 1.06473}, {3.36738, 0.0000640336}, 

  {3.32268, 1.06514}, {3.42149, 0.0000661463}, {3.37624, 1.06555}, {3.47647, 0.0000683287}, {3.43067, 1.06597}, {3.53232, 0.0000707956}, 

  {3.48597, 1.06638}, {3.58905, 0.0000736094}, {3.54216, 1.06679}, {3.64669, 0.0000764967}, {3.59926, 1.06721}, {3.70524, 0.0000798165}, 

  {3.65728, 1.06762}, {3.76471, 0.0000834894}, {3.71623, 1.06803}, {3.82514, 0.0000873313}, {3.77613, 1.06845}, {3.88652, 0.0000915333}, 

  {3.837, 1.06886}, {3.94886, 0.0000963229}, {3.89886, 1.06928}, {4.0122, 0.000101516}, {3.9617, 1.06969}, {4.07654, 0.000107257}, {4.02556, 1.07011}, 

  {4.14188, 0.000113664}, {4.09046, 1.07052}, {4.20824, 0.000121301}, {4.15639, 1.07093}, {4.27561, 0.000130168}, {4.22339, 1.07135}, 

  {4.34401, 0.000140948}, {4.29147, 1.07176}, {4.41342, 0.000154391}, {4.36065, 1.07218}, {4.48386, 0.000171334}, {4.43094, 1.0726}, 

  {4.55203, 0.00019224}, {4.50236, 1.07301}, {4.61449, 0.000216568}, {4.57494, 1.07343}, {4.67437, 0.00024562}, {4.64869, 1.07384}, 

  {4.73498, 0.000280281}, {4.72362, 1.07426}, {4.79079, 0.000320334}, {4.8375, 0.000361259}, {4.79976, 1.07521}, {4.87893, 0.000410179}, 

  {4.91439, 0.000464428}, {4.87722, 1.0633}, {4.88886, 0.929875}, {4.88977, 0.823673}, {4.89067, 0.7296}, {4.89158, 0.646272}, {4.89248, 0.57246}, 

  {4.89339, 0.507079}, {4.89429, 0.449165}, {4.89519, 0.397865}, {4.8961, 0.352425}, {4.89701, 0.312174}, {4.89791, 0.27652}, {4.89882, 0.244938}, 

  {4.89972, 0.216964}, {4.90063, 0.192184}, {4.90153, 0.170234}, {4.90244, 0.150792}, {4.90335, 0.13357}, {4.90425, 0.118314}, {4.90516, 0.104802}, 

  {4.90607, 0.0928321}, {4.90697, 0.0822297}, {4.90788, 0.0728381}, {4.90879, 0.0645192}, {4.9097, 0.0571504}, {4.9106, 0.0506232}, 

  {4.91151, 0.0448414}, {4.91242, 0.0397201}, {4.91333, 0.0351836}, {4.91424, 0.0311652}, {4.91514, 0.0276058}, {4.91605, 0.0244529}, 

  {4.91696, 0.0216601}, {4.91787, 0.0191863}, {4.91878, 0.016995}, {4.91969, 0.015054}, {4.9206, 0.0133347}, {4.92151, 0.0118117}, 

  {4.92242, 0.0104627}, {4.92333, 0.00926771}, {4.92424, 0.00820923}, {4.92515, 0.00727164}, {4.92606, 0.00644114}, {4.92697, 0.00570549}, 

  {4.92788, 0.00505386}, {4.92879, 0.00447665}, {4.9297, 0.00396537}, {4.93062, 0.00351248}, {4.93153, 0.00311132}, {4.93244, 0.00275597}, 

  {4.93335, 0.00244121}, {4.93426, 0.00216239}, {4.93518, 0.00191542}, {4.93609, 0.00169666}, {4.937, 0.00150288}, {4.93791, 0.00133124}, 

  {4.93883, 0.0011792}, {4.93974, 0.00104452}, {4.94065, 0.000925222}, {4.94157, 0.000819552}, {4.94248, 0.00072595}, {4.94339, 0.000643038}, {4.94814, 0.000552088}, {4.93442, 0.000506373}, {4.92348, 1.06943}}
```

It corresponds to some contour. When I'm trying to plot it using `ListLogLogPlot`, it shows the contour correctly, but when I'm trying to use the option `Joined->True`, then instead of joining the point-neighbors it joins points located very far from each others.

What is the reason for this and how to avoid it?

Comment: I guess it was not you, who sorted the list of points by the first coordinate? Usually software tools would already give you the list in a meaningful order, such that you can just connect them in the order given in the list of points.

Comment: @Johu : I used web plot digitizer with the option "Sort by the nearest neighbors", but this didn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** Stitching multiple paths produces by `FindCurvePath` into a single path:

```
ClearAll[chain, stichPaths]
chain = # //. 
  {a___, p1 : {b_, ___}, c___, p2 : {b_, ___}, e___} :> {a, Reverse @ p1, p2, c, e} //. 
  {a___, p1 : {___, b1_}, c___, p2 : {___, b2_}, e___} /; Abs[b1 - b2] <= 1 :> 
     {a, p1, Reverse @ p2, c, e} &;

stichPaths[data_] := Module[{pts = data[[#]] & /@ FindCurvePath[data], nFs, range, path, 
   newpts},
  range = Range[Length@pts];
  nFs = Nearest /@ (Join @@ Drop[pts[[All, {1, -1}]], #] & /@ range);
  newpts = Join @@ (Join[nFs[[#]][ pts[[#, 1]]], pts[[#]], 
        nFs[[#]][ pts[[#, -1]]]] & /@ range);
  path = Append[#, #[[1]]] &[Join @@ (chain@FindCurvePath[newpts])]; 
  newpts[[path]]]

ListLogLogPlot[stichPaths[DataTable], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

Re-ordering the input data using [`FindShortestTour`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindShortestTour.html) seems to work:

```
ListLogLogPlot[DataTable, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

```
ListLogLogPlot[DataTable[[FindShortestTour[DataTable][[2]]]], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

You can also use [`ListCurvePathPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCurvePathPlot.html) and [`FindCurvePath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCurvePath.html)

```
pts1 =  Cases[ListCurvePathPlot[DataTable], Line[x_] :> x, Infinity];
ListLogLogPlot[pts1, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

```
pts2 = DataTable[[#]] & /@ FindCurvePath[DataTable];
ListLogLogPlot[pts2, Joined -> True]
```

> same picture

Both need further processing to get a single curve.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer helped me. However, when I'm trying to apply this method to another set of data, it joints most of the points correctly, but there are few points which are connected not in a shortest way. How do you think, is there any general reason for this?

Comment: I have found the reason. My second data have very small distance between y coordinates, smaller than between x. However, the values y themselves are very small. Therefore such option helped:

DataTable[[FindShortestTour[{#[[1]], Log10[#[[2]]]} & /@DataTable][[2]]]]